# To edit the file in sublime ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I just wrote a code in python to check disk_usage.I had a small error and i figured it out.But i can not edit the code in sublime.I changed the permissions to read,write and Executable.Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried other text editors (especially terminal, like vim)?

Comment: What does "can not edit the code" mean? What exactly happens when you try?

Comment: @KeithThompson Thompson Actually it is not allowing me to overwrite the file but i have change the permission

Comment: @Korgan, I tried in nano it works fine

Comment: yeah I too tried in nano it works but i want to edit in sublime.